# Using ADO.NET Entity in asp.net webpages?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, razor, html

Alright so here what i did, i created an empty Asp.net website, created a database with small table, and then i right clicked the solution explorer > Add new Item > ADO.NET Entity data model

Then i generated it from the database, now whenever i try to use it in the following form :

```
ModelName.Entity db = new ModelName.Entity();
```

i get an error that says " **The Type or namespace couldn't be found** " While the entity was saved in the folder "App_code".

any idea ?

Comment: I strongly recommend against using the Web Site "projects" (File->New Web Site). Use File->New Web Application instead.

Comment: Well, i tried and i couldn't either make a razor webpage or use the entity in a normal class.

Comment: Sorry, you tried _what_? And exactly what did you then try that didn't work?

Comment: i used your way ( New > Project > ASP.NET Empty web application ), then created database with table, and and the ado.net entity, afterwards i went to the solution explorer, right clicked > new > class , tried to use the entity in the class but i couldn't.

Comment: Please be _specific_. What do you mean, "I couldn't"? What happened when you tried? That works, in general. Since it failed, it must have failed for a _specific_ reason.

Comment: @JohnSaunders The Web Pages framework doesn't support Web Application Projects.

Comment: @MikeBrind: that's one of the things the OP might have been more specific about.

Comment: Are you using the "web pages framework"? Again, be specific, as most people reading this do _not_ use the "web pages framework".

Comment: nevermind i just picked it so instead of empty website i made a website with some components (contact,about and home pages) and other  stuff along with folder called "bin" , i guess i needed some references, thanks anyways.